# Webpack for production does not work with react-router browserHistory?

Tags: web-applications, reactjs, webpack, react-router, browser-history

however webpack -p works for hashHistory, and the browserHistory works in webpack-dev-server just not with webpack -p.

here is my routes file:
[image]

here is my webpack config file:
[image]